# Describing the location of the thalamic adhesion in simple English

Tags: human-anatomy

I'm trying to describe the location of the thalamic adhesion as part of a personal project. I can't reference pictures, and I need to be as precise as possible without using convenient anatomical terms (e.g., dorsal, superior, etc.).

I have to use plain and simple English, with a consideration for people who speak English as a second language. My approach is to describe its location relative to more prominent and easily recognized body parts (e.g., bones and organs on the face or side of the head).

In every English construction I've tried, I first start by describing it as being located in the *middle of the head*. Then I describe its location in reference to common body parts on the transverse and coronal planes.

Most X-ray pictures I've found are only somewhat helpful to me here, because they're a sagittal cutaway of the head but they don't include the ear. Based on the X-rays, I'm confident that it's located at about the same level as the eyebrow ridge on the transverse plane.

The big problem I keep running into here, is that almost every drawing and rendering I find on the internet seems to put the thalamus in different locations on the coronal plane. This makes it pretty hard for me to find a precise coronal location for the thalamic adhesion.

In some of them it seems to be where the tragus of the ear meets the mandible. Some of them draw it further forward, more towards the mandible. In other illustrations it's drawn further back, almost directly above the helix of the ear.

I'm not a physician and I can't remember how many years ago it was that I took an anatomy and physiology class. **So my question is, where is the thalamic adhesion *actually* located in the human body on the coronal plane? Is it in line with the tragus, or the ear canal, or some part of the mandible, or does it vary from person to person?**

---

Here are two possible translations of the above into simple English constructions:

> The "thalamic adhesion" is in the middle of the head, as high as the eyebrow ridge, and as far back as the ear canal
>
> The "thalamic adhesion" is in the middle of the head, as high as the eyebrow ridge, and as far back as the temple

**Secondary question: could anyone with a more expert knowledge of human anatomy suggest better constructions?**